# How to wrap an REST API client in an Actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, spray-json

I'm trying to write an actor that calls an HTTP REST API. The rest API needs a query parameter that will be passed from the invoking Actor. The [official documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html) has an example to achieve the above using a preStart method that pipes the message to itself:

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorLogging }
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.stream.{ ActorMaterializer, ActorMaterializerSettings }
import akka.util.ByteString

class Myself extends Actor
  with ActorLogging {

  import akka.pattern.pipe
  import context.dispatcher

  final implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(context.system))

  val http = Http(context.system)

  override def preStart() = {
    http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))
      .pipeTo(self)
  }

  def receive = {
    case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) =>
      entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).foreach { body =>
        log.info("Got response, body: " + body.utf8String)
      }
    case resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
      log.info("Request failed, response code: " + code)
      resp.discardEntityBytes()
  }

}
```

The above works but the URL is hardcoded. What I want to achieve is a REST client actor that I can send parameters as a message to and get back results of the call. I modified the code above to receive parameters as message (pseudo code):

```
      def receive = {

case param: RESTAPIParameter => {
            http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(URI("http://my-rest-url").withQuery("name", "value"))
                .pipeTo(self)
          }

        case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) =>
          entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).foreach { body =>
            log.info("Got response, body: " + body.utf8String)
            sender! body.utf8String    //Will not work
          }
        case resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
          log.info("Request failed, response code: " + code)
          resp.discardEntityBytes()
      }
```

The above should work, but can't really be used to send a response back to the client as the `sender` reference is lost when the result of REST call is piped back to `self`.

I guess I could try and store the sender locally in a variable and use it to pass the response back, but I don't think that is a great idea.

So, what is the right way to handle such a scenario?

**Edit**: The solution suggested below by @PH88 works, but I would like to keep the pattern matching on `HttpResponse` in the outer loop.

**Edit 2**: The reason I wanted to pipe the response back to `self` is because I wanted to implement a state machine ..kind of. The state changes based on the type of message received by the actor. As an example:

1. The first state could be receiving a query string from a calling actor. The actor invokes the REST api and `becomes` awaitingResult. Data piped to self for further processing.
2. When it receives an HTTPResponse with success code, the state `becomes` `dataRecevied`. Data is piped to `self` again for more processing.
3. The received data is then transformed into internal vendor neutral format and the result is finally sent back to the calling actor.
4. If the Response code is not successful in 1 above, the state could be changed to HttpError and handled accordingly.

Hope that clarifies the intent. Any other suggestions/designs to achieve a clean/simple design are welcome :-)

Comment: This seems to be a bad design: (1) The original `sender` will only receive a value if there was a `StatusCodes.OK` in the `HttpResponse`.  Otherwise, the sender will just keep waiting until a timeout.  Timeouts shouldn't be meaningful (2) Why would you have the response piped back to `Myself` instead of sending it back to the original sender?  (3) Why use Actor at all?  The original sender is likely doing something like `val respBody = (myselfRef ? args).mapTo[String]`; they could just as easily do `val respBody = http.singleRequest(...).flatMap(_.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `HttpResponse` with your own case class and bundle the sender with it:

```
case class ServerResponse(requester: ActorRef, resp: HttpResponse)
```

then:

```
  def receive = {

    case param: RESTAPIParameter => {
        val requester = sender
        http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(URI("http://my-rest-url").withQuery("name", "value"))
            .map(httpResp =>
               // This will execute in some other thread, thus
               // it's important to NOT use sender directly 
               ServerResponse(requester, httpResp)
            )
            .pipeTo(self)
      }

    case ServerResponse(requester, HttpResponse(...)) =>
      val result = ...
      requester ! result

    ...
  }
```

Comment: Nice..but then I lose the pattern matching on HttpStatusCode ..would prefer a way to still keep the pattern matching on HttpStatusCode on outer level instead of nesting it inside `ServerResponse`

Comment: What is your concern on doing pattern matching like: `ServerResponse(requester, HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _))` ?

Answer (score 0):

The [`pipeTo`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/index.html#akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture@pipeTo(recipient:akka.actor.ActorRef)(implicitsender:akka.actor.ActorRef):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) method takes in the sender as an implicit argument:

```
def pipeTo(recipient: ActorRef)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Future[T]
```

[Within an Actor](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/#akka.actor.Actor) `self` is defined as an implicit `ActorRef`:

```
implicit final val self: ActorRef
```

Therefore `self` is the sender that is being specified in pipeTo.

You can simply specify the sender explicitly to be the original sender:

```
def receive = {

  case param: RESTAPIParameter => 
     http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(URI("http://my-rest-url").withQuery("name", "value"))
         .pipeTo(self)(sender)  //specify original sender

  case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) =>
    entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).foreach { body =>
      log.info("Got response, body: " + body.utf8String)
      sender! body.utf8String    //Works now!
    }

  case resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) => {
    log.info("Request failed, response code: " + code)
    resp.discardEntityBytes()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments and for raising the issues. Please refer to the edit for the reasoning/intent behind the design. The code was further simplified here - the final code will handle failures as well.

Comment: @MojoJojo You are welcome.  Did specifying the sender in pipeTo solve your problem?